# Amazing integral with square of a series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, integration, special-functions

I want to integrate the following amazing integral with Legendre Polynomials. If you need it for your solution, it might be good to know, that the series converges absolutely. I do not really have an idea:

$$\int_0^{\pi} \left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} f(l) P_l(\cos(\theta))\right)^2sin(\theta) d \theta $$

Comment: "Amazing"? It looks nightmarish to me...:)

Comment: oh please tell me, that you just had a good idea...

Comment: Not even close, @Lipschitz. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried a $u$-substitution with $u = \cos(\theta)$?

Comment: yeah that was my first intuition and probably one could write this as a double sum and move the integral inside and use orthogonality of the Legendre Polynomials, as one could understand $1=P_0(cos(\theta))$. But somehow I failed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change of variable $u = \cos(\theta)$ then you get

$$\int_{-1}^1\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}f(l)P_l(u)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(k)P_k(u)du = \int_{-1}^1\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^lf(l)f(j-l)P_l(u)P_{k-l}(u)du$$

From there, make use of what I hope is uniform convergence of your series and interchange the sum and integral and make use of orthogonality of Legendre polynomials.

Comment: Great, but one thing. did you write that before or after my comment?